# how to convert world space position to screen space uv in Unity shader?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, rendering, hlsl

I first reconstruct the world position through the depth texture, and then I convert the world position to screen space UV in Unity shader, but the result seems quite wrong, In which step I made mistakes?
[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2Jsu.png)

[wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nB68.png)

[correct result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zrHN.png)

I tried visualize the depth and the reconstructed world position, and they're correct, but the generated screen space UV is wrong.